# How to add text to ngx-mat-select-search - select all checkbox?

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I'm using ngx-mat-select-search and i need to add text near the select all checkbox - like in the following picture

[image]

The problem is that i can't get to checkbox's properties since the ngx-mat-select-search is a directive , any suggestions ?

[Here is a code for reference](https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could file a PR that adds content transclusion next to the checkbox, e.g. with an attribute:

https://github.com/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search/blob/7a0ab6061c62b8aeff556763403c36eea721568f/src/app/mat-select-search/mat-select-search.component.html#L20

```
<ng-content select=„[toggleAllText]“>
```

And use it like this

```
<ngx-mat-select-search>
  <div toggleAllText>my text</div>
</ngx-mat-select-search>
```